# How to remove the space on the left and right of the chart in chart js

Tags: chart.js

How to remove the space on the left and right of the chart in chart js
I removed the bottom, I don't know how on the sides

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKJ9u.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2171V.png)

Me need to remove the space on the left and right of the chart in chart js v4.4.0

I didn't find an answer, so I'm asking for your help